# Information File Store

Tags: java, file-io

I am looking for the best possible way to create a file store.  In this file store I will be storing information on contact details etc. I will need to modify the details in the text file.  I just wanted to get some opinions of what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the size of the project.

- For small projects: you can use something simple like XML, JSON, etc...
- For bigger projects: you should use an SQL database, like MySQL, SQLite (very handy!)

And it is always nice to use SQLite! It is a simple SQL database library that stores the databases in one single file.

---

Since you have to use something simple with basic File IO, I would suggest taking one of the simple formats, like XML, JSON, CSV. Or to score better, write your own binary files, using DataOutputStream and DataInputStream.

Your file format could be something like this:

- arbitrary number of bytes: fixed header (like: "PendoContactsFormat")
- 4 bytes (ie: int), number of contacts

  - (for each contact:)
  - 2 bytes (ie: short), number of fields in this contact

    - (for each field in this contact:)
    - 2 bytes: size of the field header
    - n bytes: field header
    - 2 bytes: size of the field value
    - n bytes: field value

Comment: I forgot to add in the homework tag.  Its a college project.  I need to use File I/O.

Comment: Check out my edit. It is really worth trying to make your own format.

Comment: @Martijin Courteaux Im just taking a look at CSV to try and understand what im doing because at the moment im clueless.

Answer (score 1):

[CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) may be the right format, if you want to be able to edit this file manually and let non-programmers to edit it.